# me sale esto Warning: unlink(../uploads/): Is a directory in /var/sites/r

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, imagen, select

Estoy tratando de borrar un registro, cuya ruta está en la base de datos, y la imagen de ese registro que está alojada en la carpeta del servidor. Éste es mi código en `php`:

Aquí hago el enlace en la página `mostrar.php`:

```
<a href="javascript: eliminar_documento('<? echo $id_enc;?>');" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-placement="top" title="Eliminar">
```

Aquí realizo la función de `eliminar.php`

```
<?php
    $id = decrypt($_GET["id"], "rbb");
    $dao_documento->eliminar($id);
    header("Location: documentos.php");
    }
?>
```

En esta parte, mover la imagen a la carpeta, seleccionar y borrar. Esto está en el archivo `DEO.class.php`:

```
public function editar($documento){
    $name_imagen=$_FILES['doc_imagen']['name'];
    $ruta=$_FILES['doc_imagen']['tmp_name'];
    $folder1='../uploads/'. $name_imagen;
    $folder = substr("$folder1", 42);
    move_uploaded_file($ruta, $folder1);

    $image = $documento->image;
    $cnx = Conexion::getInstancia();
    $query = "UPDATE documento SET image = '$folder' WHERE documento_id = '$documento_id'";
    mysql_query($query, $cnx->enlace);
}

public function eliminar($documento_id){        
    $cnx = Conexion::getInstancia();
    $query1="SELECT image FROM documento where documento_id = '$documento_id'";
    $res=mysql_query($cn,$sql);
    if ($res){

        $query ="DELETE FROM documento WHERE documento_id = '$documento_id'";
        unlink($folder);
        mysql_query($query, $cnx->enlace);
    }
}
```

No sé qué estoy haciendo mal puesto que hasta lo intenté con `select` y me sigue saliendo el error `Warning: unlink(../uploads/): Is a directory in /var/sites/r`

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema está en que [`unlink`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) se utiliza para eliminar ficheros y no directorios.

Lo primero que debes hacer es eliminar todo lo que haya en el interior del directorio, esta vez sí, utilizando `unlink`. Una vez finalizado este paso, utiliza [`rmdir`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php) para eliminar el directorio.

Ejemplo directo de la documentación:

```
<?php 
    public static function delTree($dir) { 
       $files = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('.','..')); 
        foreach ($files as $file) { 
          (is_dir("$dir/$file")) ? delTree("$dir/$file") : unlink("$dir/$file"); 
        } 
        return rmdir($dir); 
    } 
?>
```